# gVim ImportErrror: module not found, even though module is in same folder as script

Tags: python, vim, python-import

I am using gVim with Windows 7.

I am trying to run a python script using the `pyfile %` command, but every time I do so, I get `ImportError: No module named libtcodpy`

Checking the location of the libtcodpy, it is indeed in the same folder as the script I am trying to run. Furthermore, running the program with the python IDE works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is vim set to the same working directory as the python file?

Comment: @FDinoff A quick `:pwd` and `:set autochdir` has solved the problem, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not automatically search the current script's directory for imports, only some configured ones (cp. `:help python-_get_paths`), and the current working directory.

So, you either need to configure the current script's path, or simply `:cd %:h` to it (alternatively automatically via `:set autochdir`).